# Spring boot relationship delete some items

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm having a bad time finding out the best approach for deleting items in a large list.
I have a "Theme" entity, that has a List relationship with "ThemeSection"

Now - A theme can have thousands of sections, and sometimes I need to delete just some sections, maybe 5 or 10.

Maybe I don't understand Spring boot enough, but the best approach for me would be:

```
List<ThemeSection> themeSections = theme.getThemeSections();
themeSections.removeAll(listOfItemsToBeDeleted)
```

However, the first line will fetch 1000 sections or more, how do I delete just a few sections that I have chosen, **that also is related to the "Theme"** without fetching the whole list..

Let me know if you need more details!

Comment: You’ll probably need to use JPQL or raw SQL to delete the items. But note that if you have an indexed `List` in the database- i.e. with an index column to preserve order - you’ll still need to fetch all 1000 items - and worse, update all the remaining one with new indexes!

Comment: Really? What if I had a list of 100.000 items, would that be the same case? This seems really stupid or am I missing something?

Is there any other way to implement such feature, that I can delete some rows that has a relationship with a Theme?

Comment: A `List` is a `List` - if you want to maintain order then removal of an item is `O(n)` by definition.

Comment: So I have to make a custom query to delete items which a section id?

Comment: As mentioned, it depends on your mapping. If you’ve asked JPA to keep order with an index then there is no escaping that cost. If you haven’t then you can delete with a query.

Comment: Okay, so another approach would be to not have a relationship with JPA, but have a custom query in my repository that have a where clause to delete all sections in list and where theme id equals theme?